# Does "steal the bread from the weak little boy" refer to any 80's movie/TV show?

Tags: dialogue, halt-and-catch-fire

Here's the dialog from the season 2 of Halt and Catch Fire TV series (the show takes place in 1984. Tom and Cameron are discussing their future computer game):

> T. Rendon (*trying to mimic weird accent*): It will be excellent
>   game, **like steal the bread from the weak little boy**. It is good
>   impersonation I do.
>
> Cameron Howe (*with same accent*): If you were impersonating the
>   cyborg sent to kill Sarah Connor.
>
> T. Rendon: Oh, damn, that came out today.

The question is does Tom refer to something in his phrase in bold?

Or could it be that Tom is just trying to mimic Russian that Arki (one of their team member) speaks, and Cameron treats Russian and Arnie's Austrian as the same gibberish accents? In fact, she mimics Austrian a minute later in her "your clothes, give them to me now" line, however, this is not the same accent as in the dialog above.

Comment: You do realize that "your clothes, give them to me" is [a reference to The Terminator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuUwW4Wi0-o), right?

Comment: @BCdotWEB, yes, that's why I wrote "Arnie's Austrian"